# UDP: why result of function send fails

Tags: sockets, udp, client-server

I am trying to send message with `UDP protocol` from client to server.
But

```
function send(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0) 
<socket.h>
```

which I use for send buffer returns -1, any time when I call it.

In description of `func` i read about results and i know if result = 0 or below - function finished with errors, and if result > 0 function successfully finised.

for example:
result of calling

`send(socket, "1.2.3.4", 7, 0)` will be -1.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show how you opened `socket`, i.e. this variable, how is it constructed?

Comment: You probably want `sendto` if you are using `UDP`. If you want to use `send` you _must_ call `connect` on the socket.

Comment: int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0); // create soccket

after calling "sock" > 0, so it will be success

Comment: "If you want to use send you must call connect on the socket. ( cnicutar)", i did not consider this, thank you cnicutar